# Why is the differential of a differential 1-form (or the wedge product) defined as it is?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, definition

In his Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, Edwards *defines* the differential $d\omega$ of a differential 1-form $\omega=Pdx+Qdy$ to be

$$d\omega\equiv\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dxdy.$$

But that definition seems cut from whole cloth.  He gives some motivating examples before and after the definition, but they don't give me a good intuitive sense of what it really means.

He has mumbled a bit about the wedge product, but not by that name.  He does not use it to derive the differential of a 1-form.

*Why is $d\omega$ defined this way?*

Or *why is the wedge product used to multiply differential forms?*

Or *is there a way to picture either $d\omega$ or the wedge product?*
I note that, if the wedge product has already been introduced as

$$dx^{1}\wedge dx^{1}=dx^{2}\wedge dx^{2}=0,$$

$$dx^{1}\wedge dx^{2}=-dx^{2}\wedge dx^{1}=1,$$

and 
$$dx^{i}dx^{j}\equiv dx^{i}\wedge dx^{j}$$
has been asserted, the differential of $\omega$ can be derived as follows:

Start with the definition of differentiability

$$0=\lim_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}\to\mathfrak{0}}\frac{\Delta\omega_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]-d\omega_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}$$

$$=\lim_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}\to\mathfrak{0}}\frac{\Delta P_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]dx+\Delta Q_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]dy-d\omega_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}.$$

Take the constant objects $dx,dy$ outside the limits, but keep them in the same relative positions

$$0=\lim_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}\to\mathfrak{0}}\left[\frac{\Delta P_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\right]dx+\lim_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}\to\mathfrak{0}}\left[\frac{\Delta Q_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\right]dy-\lim_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}\to\mathfrak{0}}\left[\frac{d\omega_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\right]$$

Apply the defintion of differentiability to P:

$$\lim_{\Delta\mathfrak{x}\to\mathfrak{0}}\left[\frac{\Delta P_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}-\frac{dP_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right]}{\left|\Delta\mathfrak{x}\right|}\right]=0$$

$$\nabla\left[P\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]\right]\cdot\mathfrak{v}=dP_{\mathfrak{x}}\left[\mathfrak{v}\right]$$

$$=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dy\right)\left[\mathfrak{v}\right]$$

$$=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}dx\left[\mathfrak{v}\right]+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dy\left[\mathfrak{v}\right]$$

$$=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}v^{x}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}v^{y}.$$

So

$$dP_{\mathfrak{x}}=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dy\right).$$

The same applies to $dQ_{\mathfrak{x}}$.

The differential is now:

$$d\omega_{\mathfrak{x}}=dP_{\mathfrak{x}}dx+dQ_{\mathfrak{x}}dy$$

$$=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dy\right)_{\mathfrak{x}}dx+\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}dy\right)_{\mathfrak{x}}dy.$$

$$=\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)_{\mathfrak{x}}dxdy.$$

Comment: These are complicated questions and they don't have short answers. One possible answer, which is a little unsatisfying, is "to make Green's theorem true."

Comment: That $dx^1\wedge dx^2 = 1$ looks quite wrong. "Is there a way to picture the wedge product?" It can be thought of as a parallelogram, or a disk, or a plane weighted with a scalar. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector

Comment: I guess that the $dx^1\wedge dx^2=1$ mistake is from the fact that its integral over the unit square is $1$. But this integration does not act like a scalar; the form $dx^1\wedge dx^2$ is being applied to the square's tangent bivectors. The form itself is a cotangent bivector.

Answer (score 0):

Upon review, I discovered that Edwards gives *his* excuse for the definition of the product of differential forms being the implied wedge product.

Note on notation: Edwards represents the absolute value of the Jacobian by

$$\left|\frac{d\mathfrak{x}}{d\mathfrak{u}}\right|.$$

After deriving the change of variables forumula for an integral; given as

> $$\int_{T\left[Q\right]}f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]d\mathfrak{x}=\int_{Q}f\left[T\left[\mathfrak{u}\right]\right]\left|\frac{d\mathfrak{x}}{d\mathfrak{u}}\right|d\mathfrak{x},$$

Edwards infroms his reader:

> This observation leads to an interpretation of the change of variables formula as the result of a “mechanical” substitution procedure. Suppose $T$ is a differentiable mapping from $uv$-space to $xy$-space. In the integral $\int_{T\left[Q\right]}f\left[x,y\right]dxdy$ we want to make the substitutions
>
> $$dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}dv,dx=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv$$
>
> suggested by the chain rule. In formally multiplying together these two “differential forms,” we agree to the conventions
>
> $$dudu=dvdv=0\text{ and }dudv=-dvdu,$$
>
> for *no* other reason than that they are necessary if we are to get the “right” answer.

Emphasis on *no* is in the original.  So I will emphasize the entire phrase:

> **for *no* other reason than that they are necessary if we are to get the “right” answer.**

I do not like that "justification", but my reasons should be addressed in a different post.

Comment: I don't like that reason either, nor "differential forms" in general. There is a system called "geometric calculus" which generalizes and unifies a bunch of things, and I find it easy to understand and visualize. Its fundamental integration theorem uses the geometric product instead of the wedge product (though the wedge can be defined in terms of the geometric product). One possible objection is that this product requires (or induces) a metric, unlike the wedge. See Alan Macdonald's videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JQxOYL3vhY , or Wikipedia, or http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/html/UGC.html

Comment: Differential forms are a necessary "evil" for me.  They are used extensively in areas of physics that interest me.  I don't believe differential forms are all that bad of an idea, per se.  I just think the typical exposition is misguided, and therefore misleading.   Box 2.3 on Page 63 of Gravitation by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler is a good example.  It sets up a straw-man about how I supposedly learned calculus, and then tells me the newfangled way is correct, whereas the way I learned it is wrong.  Well, I never met their straw-man.  I will follow up on your suggestion; time permitting.